# Is it possible to build electrical space engine based on Electromagnetic induction

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, rocket-science

Electromagnetic induction means magnet convert it momentum to an electrical current.  So I wonder if it possible to use this phenomeno for making an enigne which will accelerate a magnet And  the magnet will push the spacecraft but some sort of coil will slow doen  the magnet on when it getting back so it won't push the aircraft back

Comment: See this book: Kaku, Michio. *Physics of the Impossible*: A scientific exploration into the world of phasers, force fields, teleportation, and time travel. Anchor Books, NY. 2008. There is a discussion of similar magnetic craft (Part I, Sec. 9) "starships"; which uses harvested primordial magnetic monopoles to power a craft via galactic fields. Interesting and fun read!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming radiation losses are negligible this will not provide any net propulsion. The momentum gained by pushing the magnet will be lost by stopping the magnet. And the distance moved will be reversed by recovering the magnet.

Comment: I dont see why momentum being converted to electricity

Comment: The idea is that the magnet will move in circle and then will slow down in one side also this loses will happend due radiation between the coild and the magnet

Comment: @daniel the reason why is that momentum is conserved.